# O que fazer quando o jboss fica assim?

Tags: jboss, demoiselle

Já fazem uns 30 minutos e não sai do canto.... E outra ,dá outra vez que cancelei abruptamente o jboss exbia um erro.

Não sei o que fazer agora...[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verificar os serviços (services.msc) e vê se não tem outro jboss já utilizando a porta.

Comment: você conseguiu resolver seu problema?
Ainda precisa de ajuda?

Comment: consegui resolver meu amigo...usei outro framework não usei o demoiselle rsrs pode fechar a pergunta